# Sharing and Transposing Trad Jazz songs between Key/Clef

Tags: sheet-music, musescore

If this should be moved to a different forum, please advise and I will do so.

I just started using MuseScore, which is a free software though they probably have a pro version, and was able to score "Between the Devil and the Deep Blue Sea" in about an hour as a newbie.

I play Bb Tenor Sax, and have the "Dixieland Real Book" in Bb, but I was scoring this in Bass Clef, in concert C, for a trombonist in our band.  The fact is that I don't think that there is even a bass clef version of the Dixieland book, in any key.

For the songs we are rehearsing, I can probably do this in a reasonable amount of time, but since the song is now digital I can transpose or change clef at will - which is cool.  Is it legal to share this file with others, as well as receive MuseScore format files from others in the community?  And if so, are there any resources for this?  I have only found a forum on MuseScore so far and it doesn't appear to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the material is copyright, it remains copyright despite you illegally copying and/or modifing it.

In the case of the Dixieland book, though the book format may be copyright, the tunes aren't.

There's only one version of MuseScore, and you seem to have it.

Your trombonist would be well advised to come to terms with reading treble clef, both 'In C' and 'In Bb'.   Otherwise he's going to spend mush of his life 'writing stuff out'.